# How to decrypt Secure String values in Parameter Store using .NET Core's AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lambda, aws-systems-manager

I have the following code in a Lambda function:

```
        var ssmConfig = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementConfig
        {
            RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2
        };

        using (var ssmClient = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(ssmConfig))
        {
            var myParameter = await ssmClient.GetParameterAsync(
                new GetParameterRequest
                {
                    Name = "myParameter",
                    WithDecryption = true
                });
```

The Lambda function has the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeParameters",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:ap-southeast-2:23314131242:parameter/myParameters/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:ap-southeast-2:23314131242:key/myKey"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am receiving the following error though:

```
Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementException: The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access
```

Using the IAM Policy Simulator, I've verified that the Lambda's role has the expected permissions.

Do I need to specify the CMK alias somehow? What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I also need to add the Lambda's role as a "key user" of the CMK. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html#key-policy-default-allow-users for details.

This can be done through the console by editing the CMK, then scrolling down to the Key Users section.